# Error in Windows 10 with use of Sparklyr in R ("Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version)...":

Tags: r, windows, sparklyr

Similar questions have been asked-and-answered, but always for non-Windows systems and most were years old, so I was hoping for guidance that was more current and intelligible. The installation and loading of Sparklyr was successful.

Error occurs after defining SparkContext object as follows:

```r
sc <- spark-connect(master = "local")
```

The error returned is:

> Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version) :
> Java version detected but couldn't parse version from: java version "14" 2020-03-17

Previous questions have suggested installing an older version of Java. Is this still the right strategy for a Windows machine? Some have referenced that it necessary to reset the JAVA_HOME environment variable  is that still necessary - if so, how? Also, I wonder which version should I download and will installation of an older version of Java screw-up other applications that depend on the latest version?

Comment: Did you try to install/reinstall Java 8?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response. Your advice is in line with that provided on older tickets of this same issue - so it is good to see some consistency.  

That said, I am not an expert on Java-related functionality.  If I install Java 8, does it 'overwrite' Java 14 - or can you have two installations at the same time?  If so, will 'downgrading' to v-8 impact other applications that may rely on the advanced features provided by v-14?

I don't want to fix one problem only to hatch another.

Comment: I am no expert in Java, so I cannot say. But judging from my own personal experience as an R developer, downgrading Java is non-problematic. If you are a Java developer, you probably need more careful consideration of your options.

Comment: Excellent.  I'll install it tomorrow and will report results.

Comment: I had the same error on my Mac - to resolve it I followed [this](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/1383#issuecomment-524615377).

Comment: @lovalery Again, please stop abusing the quote environment for error messages. All line breaks will be lost and they generally make the message much harder to read because it uses the wrong font family.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you for your feedback and sorry again. O.K. I won't use quotes anymore. I thought it was clearer to use them. And, in this particular case, it didn't seem to me that it changed the line breaks. Cheers.